# Can ayone share a DSL equivalent of the Mail Attachment Sample?

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I am looking at using spring integration for the first time: the Mail Attachment Sample in the spring integration samples is a good start and I have extended for my own purposes today with suprising ease.

However I would prefer to use the DSL while I am on a roll, but having studied the DSL examples I am somewhat lost as they are quite complex.

I would appreciate it if someone can share a DSL reimplementation of any of the spring integration samples, or provide some tips on how to go about reimplementing the Mail Attachment Sample.

Comment: I succeeded in implementing it with the DSL using java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently a DSL version of that sample, but perhaps a good starting point is the [DSL mail test cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/mail/MailTests.java#L213) ?

Comment: Thanks @gary, I did manage to cobble something together. I shall refer to those tests from now on.

Comment: Thanks - if you feel like contributing your code to the mail sample, see [the guidelines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in reimplementing it with the DSL using java 1.7. Here are the interesting bits:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow polledEmails() {

    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(
            Mail.imapInboundAdapter( "imaps://" + user + ":" + password + "@imap.gmail.com:" + imapPort + "/inbox" )
                .javaMailProperties( javaMailProperties() )
                .shouldDeleteMessages( true )
        )
        .channel( MessageChannels.direct( "incomingEmail") )
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow extractAttachments() {

    return IntegrationFlows
        .from( "incomingEmail" )
        .transform( new EmailTransformer() , "transformit" )
        .split( new EmailSplitter() , "splitIntoMessages" )
        .channel( MessageChannels.direct( "attachments") )
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow writeAttachmentAsFile() {

    return IntegrationFlows
        .from( "attachments" )
        // save attachment to file
        .handle( 
            Files.outboundAdapter( "'target/out/' + headers.directory" )
            .autoCreateDirectory( true ) )
        .get();
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedDelay( 5000 ).get();
}

private Properties javaMailProperties() {

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put( "mail.store.protocol" , "pop3" );
    properties.put( "mail.debug" , "false" );

    return properties;
}
```